# array of objects in class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I have written a simple program of array of objects in class.
Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
class employee
    {
    int name;
    public:
        void getdata(void);
        void putdata(void);
    };
void employee :: getdata(void)
        {
        cout<<"enter name:";
        cin>>name;
        }
void employee :: putdata(void)
        {
        cout<<"Name:"<<name<<endl;
        }
int main()
{   int i;
    employee manager[4];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
        manager[i].getdata();
        }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
         manager[i].putdata();
        }
return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
enter name:naveen
enter name:enter name:Name:0
Name:0
Name:134515033
naveen@naveen-Ex
```

Comment: your brackets.. the functions should be inside the class definition.

Comment: `name` is an `int` so the `cin>>name` will fail when presented with `"naveen"` and `"naveen"` will remain in the input stream, unconsumed. Use a `std::string` and _check_ the result of the input operations.

Comment: You should mark you source code and click on the `{}` symbol above the text entry field. This should help.

Comment: @Ofiris .......it is not necessary to define the function inside the class....you can dfine it outside also .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `int name;`, when you do ' cin `naveen` to name it fails, so name is not initialized.

change:

`int name;`

to

```
 #include <string>
 std::string name;
```